# How do I display non field errors and field errors after I hit the submit form button for user sign up?

Tags: python, django

I have a `UserRegistrationForm` that has an email, password and confirm password fields.

Now, I would like my form to display both [Form.non_field_errors()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.non_field_errors) and [Form.errors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors) form submission if there are errors in both the Email and password fields (e.g. invalid Email and Passwords don't match errors).

However, I am facing the issue that upon submission of my form when all fields are incorrect, only the field_errors (Enter a valid email address) show up first. Once that has been resolved and I clicked enter again, the non field errors (passwords do not match) then show up. I don't want them to show up one after another and prefer that they show up together.

[image: Image taken after I email an invalid email address and non-matching passwords.]

[image: Image taken after I after email is corrected and passwords are not matching (password2 was reset)]

Here's my code.

forms.py

```
class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="New password confirmation",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"autocomplete": "new-password"}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "email",
            "password",
        ]

    def _validate_passwords(self, password1, password2):
        password_errors = []

        try:
            validate_password(password1, self.instance)
        except ValidationError as e:
            password_errors.append(
                ValidationError(_("Weak password provided"), code="weak-password"),
            )

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            password_errors.append(
                ValidationError(_("Passwords mismatch"), code="password-mismatch"),
            )

        if len(password_errors) > 0:
            raise ValidationError(password_errors)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        email = cleaned_data.get("email")
        password1 = cleaned_data.get("password")
        password2 = cleaned_data.get("password2")

        if email and password1 and password2:
            # email is already validated at Field level
            self._validate_passwords(password1, password2)

        return super().clean()
```

registration.html

```
<div>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} 
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

models.py

```
class CustomEmailField(models.EmailField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run_validators(self, value):
        pass

    def validate(self, value, model_instance):

        if value is not None and not value.endswith("@example.com"):
            raise ValidationError("Email must end with @example.com")


class CustomUserManager(auth_models.BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("The Email field must be set")

        try:
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            validate_email(email)

        except ValidationError as e:
            print("errors: ", e)

        else:
            # execute if no exception
            user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        # Almost indentical implementation to Django's UserManager class
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_staff=True.")
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError("Superuser must have is_superuser=True.")

        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(auth_models.AbstractUser):
  
    username = None
    email = CustomEmailField(unique=True)
    email_is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["password"]  # required fields when creating a user obj


    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

views.py

```
class RegistrationView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "user/registration.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = UserRegistrationForm
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        context = {"form": form}

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()

            context["success_message"] = "We have sent you an email verification."
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("user:email-verification"))

        # form should contain some errors at this point
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: Your `UserRegistrationForm` only has a `clean()` method; it does not have specific methods for cleaning each field.  Where are you expecting the field-specific errors to come from?

Comment: Have you tried submitting the form with an empty `password2`?  That form field definition does not allow for blank values, so you should at least get the built-in field validation.

Comment: @JohnGordon Hello, for the field specific errors (Email) I think it's triggering a check internally, maybe it's own clean() function? I tried to overwrite it but no luck. The Email error still shows up before the Non-field errors.